# Object getting deconstructed when out of scope

Tags: c++

I have a class and it has an array of objects as its instance variable. Each object internally contains an `int` and a `struct`. But somehow the object gets deconstructed.

i.e.

```
class AllInput {
public:
    int numProducts;
    Product * products;

public:
    AllInput(int _numProducts, Product * _products);
};

class Product {
public:
    int sellingPrice; //Ri
    struct DemandDistribution observationDemand; //C2i

public:
    Product(
            LucyDecimal _sellingPrice, //Ri
            LucyDecimal _costPriceAssmbly);
};
```

And then I have a function that creates it:

```
AllInput* in1() {
    struct DemandDistribution * _observationDemand1 =
            (DemandDistribution*) malloc(sizeof(DemandDistribution));
    // set values
    Product * product1 = new Product(165,_observationDemand1);
    //initialize product2, product3, product4 
    Product  products[4] = { *product1, * product2,  *product3, *product4};
    AllInput* all = new AllInput(4, products);
    return all;
}
```

When i do `AllInput* in = in1()`. As soon as it is executed, I see that each product among 4 gets deconstructed (thanks to print statement in deconstructor of Product). Anything am I  missing?

PS: I need to use pointer and not references because I need to next copy it to cuda memory.

Comment: It's not good to allocate memory when you rely on the caller deleting it. I'd recommend using an std::vector or std::array for this instead. You'll still be able to copy to cuda memory.

Comment: @Ben I would be able to copy to cuda memory, sure. But I cannot call its methods as its a host function

Comment: I mean use an std::vector until you need to copy, then use the raw pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declared `Product  products[4]` on the stack, so it will be released when outscoping (leaving the function)

```
Product  products[4] = { *product1, * product2,  *product3, *product4};
AllInput* all = new AllInput(4, products);
```

When constructing the dymamicly allocated `AllInput`, if you don't copy the products into internal members of `AllInputs`, when leaving the function `in1`, `products` will be freed and the pointer saved in `AllInput` will point to junk.

So create a dynamic allocation for `products` too, or copy all the data (the array of pointers) in `AllInput`.